# CRichEditCtrl::OnMouseMove

Tags: mfc

In windows OS in MFC dialog based application, subclassed cricheditctrl,I am using green color for particular format of text( %#__#% embed text) .In onmousemove() function  if char is embed text I am displaying hand cursor.

To check a char is embed text or not, I am checking the character color using below code. I am unable to select the text(multiple charcaters) in backward since I am Calling SetSel in onmousemove() but for forward selection I am not facing any problem.

How to handle this?

```
void CMyRichEditCtrl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
long char_index=CharFromPos(point);
CHARRANGE crOld;
CHARFORMAT cf;
GetSel(crOld);
SetSel(char_index,char_index+1);
CString strString=GetSelText();
GetSelectionCharFormat(cf);
bEmbed=(!strString.IsEmpty() && cf.crTextColor == EMBEDCOLOR)?true:false;
SetSel(crOld);
if(bEmbed)m_bHandCursor=true;
CRichEditCtrl::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: May be off-topic, but shouldn't you set cursor in `OnSetCursor` instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/change-mouse-pointer-window-mfc

Comment: What is `l` in `SetSel(char_index,l+1);`? The `CharFromPos` returns a position of single character to you, and to check its format you need to select from that to the next one; why would you want to go backward? Also, I suggest to use `HideSelection` while you are setting and restoring your selection, to avoid flashing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?view=vs-2019#hideselection

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein - I tried HideSelection. It does not resolve the issue.. Enduser may select  backward/forward direction.

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein - If I move the logic for determining the m_bHandCursor to OnSetCursor, backward autoselection is working fine.